# Buddypress new profile tabs and sub tabs: How to set up url slug properly?

Tags: menu, tabs, profile, buddypress

First of all, I’ve seen alot of people trying to do a similar task, which is simply to create a new tab, with sub tabs in the user profile menu. I’ve managed to do this, but I can’t seem to get the url slug to work properly. When I click on the first sub tab, it simply takes me back to the main page for the user profile, and when I click on any additional sub tabs I get 404 errors. I have a feeling I’m missing something pretty simple, and I’ve been trying to learn over the last couple weeks how to make this work without any luck. If someone could help guide me on how to get this working properly, I would very grateful, and I imagine many others would find this post useful in the future.

For the record the main profile tab works properly, but the sub-tabs do not.

Here is the code I currently have in my bp-custom.php file

```
// My Membership Profile Tab
function profile_new_nav_item() {

global $bp;

bp_core_new_nav_item(
array(
    'name'                => 'My Membership',
    'slug'                => 'my-membership',
    'default_subnav_slug' => 'extra_sub_tab', // We add this submenu item below
    'screen_function'     => 'view_manage_tab_main'
)
);
}


add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_nav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_tab_main() {
add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_main_function' );
bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_main_function() {
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
}
}

function profile_new_subnav_item() {
global $bp;

bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
    'name'            => 'Membership Level',
    'slug'            => 'extra_sub_tab',
    'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[      'extra_tab' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
    'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'my-membership' ][ 'slug' ],
    'position'        => 10,
    'screen_function' => 'view_manage_sub_tab_main'
) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_subnav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_sub_tab_main() {
add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_sub_function' );
bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_sub_function() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //Add shortcode to display content in sub tab
    echo do_shortcode( '[membership]' );
} else {
    wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
}
}

// My Billing Profile Tab

function profile_new_subnav_item_billing() {
global $bp;

bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
    'name'            => 'Billing',
    'slug'            => 'extra_sub_tab_billing',
    'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[    'extra_tab' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
    'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'my-membership' ][ 'slug' ],
    'position'        => 20,
    'screen_function' => 'view_manage_sub_tab_billing'
) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_subnav_item_billing', 20 );

function view_manage_sub_tab_billing() {
add_action( 'bp_template_content',     'bp_template_content_sub_function_billing' );
bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_sub_function_billing() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //Add shortcode to display content in sub tab
    echo do_shortcode( '[billing]' );
} else {
    wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
 // define your parent slug
 $parent_slug = 'activity';
  bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( .........   
    'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $parent_slug.'/',
    'parent_slug'     => $parent_slug,
```

It works for me.